# Google maps setting avatar user

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Good day.

I need help in options Google maps.

My site has block with Google maps. The map has options to display avatar user if he registered in Google+ (gmail). The avatar has circle form with diametr about 32px (how in the example: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-coordinates?hl=ru).

I want that avatar has square form with size 60x60px and margin-right 70px.

How do it?

Thank you advance!

The code avatar on Google maps:

```
     <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/widget?pb=!1m2!1u22!2s12a!2sru#WzEsMTUxXQ.."
        frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"
        style="border: 0px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; right: 0px; visibility: visible; width: 37px; height: 37px;">

    <html jstcache="0">
    <head>
        <link id="__2__" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <style>div.login-control{color:white;font-family:Roboto,Arial;font-size:11px;font-weight:500}div.login{border-radius:2px;background-color:#5f84f2;padding:4px 8px 4px 8px;cursor:pointer}.login-control .tooltip-anchor{color:#5B5B5B;display:inline;font-family:Roboto,Arial;font-size:13px;font-weight:normal;-moz-user-select:text;-webkit-user-select:text;-ms-user-select:text;user-select:text;width:50%}.login-control .tooltip-content{background-color:white;font-weight:normal;right:0px}div.login a:link{text-decoration:none;color:inherit}div.login a:visited{color:inherit}div.login a:hover{text-decoration:underline}div.profile-photo{border-radius:50%;box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);width:32px;height:32px;overflow:hidden}div.profile-photo-light{background-color:white}div.profile-photo-light div{color:black}div.profile-photo-dark{background-color:black}div.profile-photo-dark:hover{background-color:white;color:black}div.profile-photo img{float:right;width:32px;height:32px}.tooltip-anchor{width:100%;position:relative;float:right;z-index:1}.tooltip-anchor>.tooltip-tip-inner{background-color:transparent;border-left:8px solid transparent;border-right:8px solid transparent;border-bottom:8px solid white;height:0;left:-8px;position:absolute;top:5px;width:0;z-index:1}.tooltip-content{border-radius:2px;box-shadow:0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);display:inline-block;line-height:100%;padding:10px 11px 9px 11px;position:absolute;margin:0;top:10px;white-space:nowrap}.tooltip-content a{color:#3a84df;text-decoration:none}.tooltip-content a:hover{text-decoration:underline}.tooltip-content .user-email,.tooltip-content .user-name{padding-right:12px}.sign-in-explanatory-text{margin-bottom:6px}.tooltip-content a{overflow:hidden}.g-logo{background-image:url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/white_google_icon.png);background-size:14px 12px;display:inline-block;height:12px;padding-right:6px;vertical-align:middle;width:8px}.gm-china .g-logo{background-image:url(http://maps.gstatic.cn/mapfiles/api-3/images/white_google_icon.png)}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.2),(min-resolution:1.2dppx),(min-resolution:116dpi){.g-logo{background-image:url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/white_google_icon_hdpi.png)}.gm-china .g-logo{background-image:url(http://maps.gstatic.cn/mapfiles/api-3/images/white_google_icon_hdpi.png)}}.sprite-sheet{background-image:url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/signed_in_api_icons2.png);background-size:100px 50px}.gm-china .sprite-sheet{background-image:url(http://maps.gstatic.cn/mapfiles/embed/images/signed_in_api_icons2.png)}@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.2),(min-resolution:1.2dppx),(min-resolution:116dpi){.sprite-sheet{background-image:url(https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/signed_in_api_icons2_hdpi.png);background-size:100px 50px}.gm-china .sprite-sheet{background-image:url(http://maps.gstatic.cn/mapfiles/embed/images/signed_in_api_icons2_hdpi.png)}}</style>
    </head>
    <body jstcache="0" style="overflow: hidden;">
    <script>
        window.parent.frames['gm-master'].initWidget(window);
    </script>
    <div jstcache="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 500px; height: 500px;">

        <div jstcache="0" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 4px;">
            <div jstcache="69" class="login-control" jsaction="mouseenter:loginControl.resize;mouseleave:loginControl.resize;loginControl.resize">
                <div jstcache="2" jsaction="loginControl.login" class="login" style="display: none">
                    <a jstcache="3"> <span class="g-logo"> </span><span>Войти</span></a>
                </div>
                <div jstcache="4" class="profile-photo-light profile-photo" jsan="7.profile-photo-light,7.profile-photo">
                    <img jstcache="5" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-R_xY89bx5Ss/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABg/xx_czODJ35o/s32-c/photo.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="tooltip-anchor">
                    <div class="tooltip-tip-inner"></div>
                    <div class="tooltip-content">
                        <div jstcache="6" class="sign-in-explanatory-text" style="display: none">Войдите в свой аккаунт, и Google Карты станут ещё удобнее</div>
                        <div>
                            <a jstcache="7" class="" style="display: none"></a>
                            <a target="_blank" jstcache="8" href="https://plus.google.com/113092786366482147078?socpid=238&amp;socfid=maps_api_v3:logincontrol" class="user-name" jsan="7.user-name,8.href,0.target">+aleksandr</a>
                            <a target="blank_" jstcache="9" href="https://support.google.com/maps/?p=thirdpartymaps&amp;hl=ru" jsaction="mouseup:loginControl.learnMore">Подробнее...</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

tag:

```
<img jstcache="5" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-R_xY89bx5Ss/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAABg/xx_czODJ35o/s32-c/photo.jpg">
```

[image]

Comment: You have to show an attempt.

Comment: How do I must to show attempt? Do I show my code? But it is the usual  connection code Google maps.
The avatar user is in iframe and I can not to get a element "div.profile-photo" in Jquery that according to the security agreement. I can not to find in Google maps API how do change size avatar user on map. What do I must to show you?

Comment: Show some code, an image or something similar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's currently not possible to customize the UI for the Signed In experience.  I'd recommend opening a feature request on the [Google Maps API Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/) describing your use case so the team can start tracking interest in it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 months old question and already chosen an answer, but if anyone else if looking for this. you can achieve the margin thing applying css directly to the iframe element.

This is the code i'm using

```
iframe[src^="https://www.google.com/maps/api/js/widget?"] {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 52px;
}
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxNZi.png)